Change background color and corner of a box using compose
Hi Everyone I am new to android compose.I want to change the background color and and make corner rounded of a box.Here is my code and reference image.

  Box(modifier = modifier) {
        Row {
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = topic.image), contentDescription = stringResource(
                id = topic.name
            ) )
            Column {
                Text(text = stringResource(id = topic.name))
                Text(text = stringResource(id = topic.pixel))
            }
        }
    }


Use clip and background extension functions on Modifier to set the color and shape of the background as demonstrated below.
Box(
    modifier = modifier
        // ====================================
        // Clipping the bounds of composable to the required bounds
        .clip(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                topStart = 12.dp,
                topEnd = 12.dp,
                bottomStart = 12.dp,
                bottomEnd = 12.dp
            )
        )
        // Set background color and corner shapes here.
        .background(
            color = Color.Black,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                topStart = 12.dp,
                topEnd = 12.dp,
                bottomStart = 12.dp,
                bottomEnd = 12.dp
            )
        )
        // ====================================
) {
    Row {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = topic.image),
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = topic.name)
        )
        Column {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = topic.name))
            Text(text = stringResource(id = topic.pixel))
        }
    }
}

